# Checking Constraints SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 columns in a table -

[SendDate] and [PayDate]

I am trying to implement a constraint that will check that - 
the product cannot be paid for if it has not been sent out.

I am not sure how to go on about it.

Any suggestions much appreciated, thanks

Comment: Just a constraint that checks that either PayDate is NULL or PayDate > SendDate?

Comment: Not sure what kind of system you are working on but what about prepaid orders or orders that have items on backorder?

Comment: This [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp) has several examples on how to add CHECK constraints to a table. The answer by notulysses will give you the condition you should check against.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
CHECK( 
  (SendDate IS NULL AND PayDate IS NULL) OR 
  (SendDate IS NOT NULL AND PayDate IS NULL) OR 
  (SendDate IS NOT NULL AND PayDate > SendDate)
 );"
```

*i.e. :*

1. order was not sent
2. order was sent but was not paid
3. order was sent and then paid